# dose Arduino Uno capable of running an application taking input from sensors and sending them to remote database?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arduino-uno

as I mentioned above,

does Arduino Uno capable of running application that is taking input from sensors around 6 sensors and sending that input to a remote database through out internet by using either (Wi-Fi shield, ethernet shield)?

I am asking such a question because I am going to use it in the next semester of academic year as a part of my final year project, but I am worried that it's RAM size is not enough since it is 2KB and I need to decide either using Arduino Uno or switch to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, altough you may have a hard time searching for a suitable driver for your database. If using MySQL, there is already [a project](https://launchpad.net/mysql-arduino) to do exactly what you want.

Another (more flexible) approach is to write a small PC software to receive sensor data in a simple protocol you define, and write them to the database. Run it on the database machine (or any other machine, really), and then make the Arduino communicate with your proxy software instead.